# Change file permission in FTP using TIdFTP Delphi

Tags: delphi, ftp, file-permissions, chmod

How do I change the permissions of a file using TidFTP in Delphi?

```
with IdFTP1 do
begin
  try
    Connect;

    ChangeDir(FTPDiretorio);
    Put(FArquivo, NomeOnline);
    chmod('        ');//640 HOW??????????????
    Disconnect;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(IdFTP1);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CHMOD` is not a standard FTP command. Some FTP servers implement it as a custom command, and others do not implement it at all.  As such, you have to use the `TIdFTP.Site()` method to send it, on FTP servers you know support it, eg:

```
IdFTP.Site('CHMOD 640 filename');
```

Comment: just the command in my case needs to uppercase and the file name is the last parameter, but is correct, Thank you.